# sort by two numerical columns

Tags: sort, bioinformatics

I am trying to sort a genetic file based on chr (column 2) and position (column 3) that both start from lower to higher.
my table is like this in large file

```
SNP CHR BP  A1  A2  effect_allele_frequency BETA    standard_error  P
rs10875231  1   100000012   T   G   0.405   -0.0456807  0.02260471  0.04335677
rs6678176   1   100000827   C   T   0.383   0.02553138  0.02287662  0.2645817
rs78590530  1   100000948   A   G   0.016   0.171376    0.08757958  0.05035017
rs149636485 1   100001060   A   G   0.004   -0.03363731 0.1819208   0.8529224
```

I want to order CHR (from 1 to 22) in a way that position also start from lower to high disregard of other columns and for each chr separately.
I tried this sort command

```
sort -t $'\t' -nk3 myfile.tsv | sort -t $'\t' -nk2  > test.txt
```

it gives order in chr (column 2) but not position (column 3). it seems that column 1 interferes:

```
SNP CHR BP  A1  A2  effect_allele_frequency BETA    standard_error  P
rs1000033   1   226580387   G   T   0.416   0.02958699  0.02295015  0.1971771
rs1000050   1   162736463   T   C   0.378   0.06136397  0.02293639  0.007468015
rs1000070   1   222359612   C   T   0.381   0.02563547  0.02294139  0.2638107
rs1000073   1   157255396   G   A   0.387   -0.01470793 0.02273634  0.517414
rs1000085   1   66857915    C   G   0.024   -0.03536382 0.07555889  0.6394446
rs1000127   1   63432716    C   T   0.157   0.003052272 0.03045933  0.919875
```

How can I sort by column 2 then 3 only?

Comment: You only have numerical chromosomes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify all keys in sort order in a single `sort` invocation, and you need to give end fields:

```
sort -n -k2,2 -k3,3
```

`sort -n -k3` means sort by comparing numbers formed by taking numeric characters starting with field 3 (after skipping blanks). Piping to a separate `sort -n -k2` sorts by the contents of the second and following fields (until a non-numeric character). But that doesn’t explain your output...

See the description of `-n` and `-k` in [the `sort` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) for details.